# MongoDB: How to create sparse+unique indexes with optional keys?

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have a collection `stats.daily` that stores multiple dimensional data, but depending the `type` it requires other specific keys.
And also it's required that these keys (depending the type) are unique.

Example, in this case `url` key is required because `type` is "url":

```
{
    "site": 1,
    "type": "url",
    "url": "http://google.com/"
    "totals": {
        "variable1": 12,  // incrementing values
        "variable2": 32
    }
}
```

Another example:

```
{
    "site": 1,
    "type": "domain",
    "domain": "google.com",
    "totals": {...}
}
```

So I create the indexes:

```
db.coll.createIndex({site: 1, type: 1, url: 1}, {unique: true, sparse: true});
db.coll.createIndex({site: 1, type: 1, domain: 1}, {unique: true, sparse: true});
```

It doesn't works, it returns `exception: E11000 duplicate key error index`.
Makes sense for the unique index, but it should work for the sparse part.

What's the best solution to accomplish what I need?

**Edit:**
In some cases, depending the `type`, there may have more than one related key:

```
{
    "site": 1,
    "type": "search",
    "engine": "google",
    "term": "programming",
    "totals": {...}
}
```

And the unique index will include these two new keys.

Comment: Could I possibly question that if you are going to all the trouble of including a "type" field then why would you vary the "data" field name like this? It just seems a little inconsistent when the field could be named ( for example ) "data" and accomplish the same thing without the need for "sparse" and using less storage space.

Comment: I know what you mean, the problem is that in some cases, depending on the `type` value, there may be more than one values' keys. Example: `{site: 1, type: 'search', search_term: 'hello', search_engine: 'google'}`.

Comment: Then why are those keys just not called "term" and "engine" respectively? You already **need** to match on documents containing `"type": "search"`. So see where I am going here? The logical course is "don't do it that way" and keep the names generic. I cannot see what you "think" you gain by doing otherwise.

Comment: And you mean using something like `search: {$exists: true}` to filter of this type? Still it doesn't resolves my problem. Since `term` or `engine` keys may sometimes be missing. And I need an unique index that includes these keys.

Comment: Not at all. Why for example does "type": "url" and "type": "domain" require any other "different" fields? Why can all the fields just not be the same? Just trying to lead you on a logical path away from the problems you are running into otherwise. These are the things you need to consider, and then if you still are not sure, add them to your question content. As it is, I personally would answer "Don't do it that way", but likely run in to all kinds of blocks from yourself saying "But I have fields like this". Make your question clear enough for definitive answers.

Comment: Got it, the usage of a single key for the value would be great. But as mentioned, sometimes I need more than one value, and sometimes all of those values are required in the unique index.

Comment: Edit your question to show your **full** case as you understand it. I think you're wrong. So please give me what I need to prove it.

Comment: Added extra context to the documents to give you a better idea. Each compound unique index, works as a key for the incrementing of several other counters in the document.

Comment: Could you please take a little more time than that. Review the comments made by yourself and please show some samples that "vary" in the sort of way you are talking about.